# chrome не обновляет task stylus

Tags: google-chrome, gulp

для моего проекта использую набор плагинов для верстки. chrome c расширением (livepage). суть проблемы такова task stylus компилируется но не обновляется в хроме. вот task

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
   stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
   watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('css', function(){
   return gulp.src('app/stylus/*.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
});
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/stylus/*.styl', ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'css', 'watch']);
```

пробовал запускать более ранний проект с таким же набором правил, все работает. не могу установить причину... возможно кто-то сталкивался уже с подобным?

**Обновление**
вообщем, ситуация странная. Я установил (live-reload). stylus начал обновляться. Но когда, дополнил свой проект с postcss ( плагины csswring & autoprefixer) начались, чудеса. запускаю gulp и chrome выдает

**Could not connect to Live-Reload server. Please, make sure that a compatible Live-Reload server is running. We recommend quard-livereload, until Live-Reload comes to your platform**.

в консоле выводит

`Container#eachAtRule is deprecated. Use Container#walkAtRule instead. Container#eachRule is deprecated. Use Container#walkRule instead. Container#eachDecl is deprecated. Use Container#walkDecl instead. Node#semicolon is deprecated. Use Node#raws.semicolon Node#after is deprecated. Use Node#raws.after Container#eachComment is deprecated. Use Cotainer#walkComments insteed. ....`

Снова переустановил live-reload осталось только сообщения в консоле ...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте связку [gulp-livereload](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload)  и расширение [livereload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei).

Предположу,  что livepage не может "добраться" до отслеживаемых файлов и поэтому не обновляет страницу. С данной связкой такой проблемы не будет. Более того вы можете создать правило на обновление страницы даже если страница генерируются сервером (т.е. на изменение jade,  html и других файлов)